# SQL Replace column with MAX value

Tags: sql, oracle, max

In Oracle SQL how can a get a table replacing a column's value with the MAX?

I have:

```
ID      Val
======= =======
1       10
2       19
3       55
4       40
```

And I want:

```
ID      Val
======= =======
1       55
2       55
3       55
4       55
```

I tried:

```
SELECT    id, MAX(Val)
FROM      table;
```

But it's complaining about the `GROUP BY`, if I add it for `id` it will return the original table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
SELECT id, MAX(Val) OVER ()
FROM table;
```

Comment: 40sec Response time, Great :)

Comment: Never heard of that before and works like a charm! thanks!